# Checkbox is not check when inserting value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save_exam').click(function(){
      var student_id=$('#student_id').val();
      var student_firstname=$('#student_firstname').val();
      var student_lastname=$('#student_lastname').val();
      var exam_name=$('#exam_name').val();
      var date=$('#date').val();

      window.location=window.location.href+'&student='+student_id+'&student_firstname='+student_firstname+'&student_lastname='+student_lastname+'&exam_name='+exam_name+'&date='+date
    });
  });
</script>
```

Query:

```
<?php 
    $sql = "select * from students where student_id = '$student_id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
      $studentid = $row['student_id'];
      $student_firstname = $row['firstname'];
      $student_lastname = $row['lastname']; 
    }

    if(isset($_GET['student_firstname']))
      {
        extract($_GET);
        $query = "select * from student_exams where exam_name = '$exam_name' and student_id ='$student_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if($row > 0 )
        {
          $msg .="<h5 style='text-align:center;color:red;'>Your Exam Detail Already Exist. Please Select Other Exam.</h5>";
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = "insert into student_exams(student_id,student_firstname,student_lastname,exam_name,date)values('$student_id','$student_firstname','$student_lastname','$exam_name','$date')";
            $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
            if($result == true)
            {
            $msg .="<h4 style='text-align:center;color:green;'>Your Data Has Been Submitted Successfully.</h4>";

            }
            else
            {
              $msg .="<h4 style='text-align:center;color:red;'>Error</h4>";
            }
        }
      }
    ?>
```

html code:

```
<form method="post">
    <?php
      if($studentid == '')
      {
        echo '';
      }
      else
      {
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="save_exam" id="save_exam">&nbsp;&nbsp;<b style="color: #337ab7;">Mark And Save This Exam</b>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="student_id" id="student_id" value="<?php echo $student_id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="student_firstname" id="student_firstname" value="<?php echo $student_firstname; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="student_lastname" id="student_lastname" value="<?php echo $student_lastname; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="exam_name" id="exam_name" value="<?php echo $exam_name; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="date" id="date">
  </form>
```

Here when I check on checkbox page reloded and inserting value into database and show message i.e. Your Data Has Been Submitted Successfully. But checkbox are not check. So, how can we do this ?

Thank You

Comment: You can add `checked` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your input to this :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="save_exam" id="save_exam" <?php session_start(); if($_SESSION['saved']=="true"){echo "checked";} ?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b style="color: #337ab7;">Mark And Save This Exam</b>
```

And query code to this:

```
<?php session_start();
    $sql = "select * from students where student_id = '$student_id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
      $studentid = $row['student_id'];
      $student_firstname = $row['firstname'];
      $student_lastname = $row['lastname']; 
    }

    if(isset($_GET['student_firstname']))
      {
        extract($_GET);
        $query = "select * from student_exams where exam_name = '$exam_name' and student_id ='$student_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if($row > 0 )
        {
          $_SESSION['saved'] = "false";// Change made HERE, this variable stores your result
          $msg .="<h5 style='text-align:center;color:red;'>Your Exam Detail Already Exist. Please Select Other Exam.</h5>";
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = "insert into student_exams(student_id,student_firstname,student_lastname,exam_name,date)values('$student_id','$student_firstname','$student_lastname','$exam_name','$date')";
            $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
            if($result == true)
            {
            $msg .="<h4 style='text-align:center;color:green;'>Your Data Has Been Submitted Successfully.</h4>";
            $_SESSION['saved'] = "true";// Change made HERE, this var stores your result

            }
            else
            {
              $_SESSION['saved'] = "false";// Again, this variable stores your result
              $msg .="<h4 style='text-align:center;color:red;'>Error</h4>";
            }
        }
      }
    ?>
```

Here I have **used sessions** to store whether the post ***was successful or not*** and depending on that I have changed the checked attribute of the checkbox. So basically `$_SESSION['saved']` stored whether the query was successful or not. If it failed then this variable contains the value `false` otherwise `true`. So the above code will help you check the input when the query was successful.

Comment: @Jeff -  The above code will check checkbox after reload.

Comment: Thank you programmingandroid

Comment: @Jeff - select as right answer and upvote if you found it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using checked='checked' attribute.
Please add checked='checked' in checkbox attribute like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="save_exam" checked='checked' id="save_exam">&nbsp;&nbsp;<b style="color: #337ab7;">Mark And Save This Exam</b>
```

Comment: If I give checked='checked' then it always show a checkbox check. I want when I click on checkbox then page will reloaded after reload page  checkbox is not check

Comment: You can put this in certain condition what ever you want.

Comment: Like conditon <?php echo ($dbvalue['tag_1']==1 ? 'checked' : '');?>